# POST AJAX call not working with Express JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, node.js, express

> This is my NodeJs File

```
var express = require('express'),
//http = require('http'),
app = express(),
bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyParser.json());         // to support JSON-encoded bodies
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({     // to support URL-encoded bodies
  extended: true
}));

app.post('/',function(req,res,next){
var result = {};
res.writeHead(200,{"Content-type":"text/plain"});
result.status = true;
res.write(JSON.stringify(result));
res.end();
});

// Default/Fallthrough method for any route not handled when using http package.
app.use(function(req,res,next){
    res.sendStatus(404);
});

app.listen(1337,function(){
    console.log("Server started successfully at Port 1337!");
});
```

> This is my AJAX request inside a .html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>tester.html</title>
</head>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h1 id="answer"></h1>

<script>

var ele = $("#answer");
//ele.append("Hello World!!!");

var datapassed = {user_name: "rv", password : "rv"};

$.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost:1337',
    async: false,
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    data : JSON.stringify(datapassed),
    contentType: "application/json",
    success: function(data) {
        alert(data);
        //  ele.append(data);
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert('error ' + textStatus + " " + errorThrown);
    }
});

</script>

</html>
```

> What my underlying goal is to make a web application which would use the API built in NodeJS using ExpressJS as the framework. AJAX is the first thing that came in my mind to make server side requests to the API to display real time data on the application. I tried everything but nothing seems to work. The AJAX call doesn't return anything. The console says

**Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)**

Any alternatives other than AJAX are welcome.

Comment: Why are you using `dataType: 'jsonp'`? What do you think that line does? What happens if you remove that line?

Comment: Did using `http://localhost:1337/` fix your problem ? (Note the / at the end)

Comment: This is what I get if I remove `dataType: 'jsonp' ` is :   **XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:1337/. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 404.**

Comment: Why did you specify JSONP? JSONP requests cannot be used over POST (they must be GET, and therefore cannot have meaningful body data),  must be asynchronous, and must receive an executable script as a response from the server. None that matches what you are doing here. Are you specifying JSONP in an attempt to allow cross-origin access? In that case, just [enable CORS](http://enable-cors.org/server_expressjs.html).

Comment: Doesn't matter if you add `/` at the end. Notwithstanding adding or not adding the `/`,  the console says :    `GET http://localhost:1337/?callback=jQuery111203430932753253728_1455570384048&{%22user_name%22:%22rv%22,%22password%22:%22rv%22}&_=1455570384049` on a red blanket.

Comment: Since the question is solved. Could anyone tell me why i got 2 down votes on my question??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, if you're using JSONP, using the HTTP `POST` method isn't possible, you can only use `GET`, because of the way JSONP works.

Second of all, you need to opt-in to JSONP support in your Express route ([source](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.jsonp)), or else it won't accept JSONP requests. So change your route to this (if you'd like to keep on using JSONP):

```
app.get('/',function(req,res,next){
  var result = {};
  result.status = true;
  res.jsonp(JSON.stringify(result));
});
```

Or change it to this if you'd like to use regular JSON:

```
app.post('/',function(req,res,next){
  var result = {};
  result.status = true;
  res.json(JSON.stringify(result));
});
```

In order to use a regular JSON request, the HTTP call would have to come from a HTML page on the same host and port as the API endpoint. You could this accomplish by letting the express server serve your HTML files by using `express.static`, like below:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/client')); //serve all files in the 'client' folder
```

Comment: Thanks a ton leroydev. Btw, I then rendered the ajax page using express JS. Since the request then was on the same host and same port and same protocol, I didn't need jsonp.